# Course review form - include link to course details

Tags: gui-design

I'm currently putting together a design for a review form for a course e-com site. However, I'm unsure whether or not I should include a link back to the course details page. My worry is that including a link would be an unnecessary distraction that could lead users away from leaving a review.

Here's part of the proposed design. The original plan was to make the course title a link back to the course details page. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Where is this placed? Do you have a larger context of the page that this appears on?

Answer (score 1):

**Include the link to the course description.** It will help users recall details about the course and leave more accurate reviews.

- Make the link open in a new tab or window. Include an icon to indicate the link will open in a new tab or window.
- Use a transient popup that includes brief course information when the user hovers over the course name.

If I could not easily refresh my memory of the course, I would likely do one of the following:

- Leave a negative review because I cannot recall what's good about the course. Negative experiences are easier to recall.
- Not leave a review at all. It's too much work to search for the course on my own, and I simply don't care enough about it to leave a review.

Another bad idea that *might* occur to you is to try to *force* users to leave reviews. When I have encountered this scenario in the past, my response has been to leave bad or neutral reviews because being forced puts me in a bad disposition, which I project onto the course. This has happened in continued education courses that require review for credit. The presenter has to far over-perform to receive positive reviews, and many may undeservedly receive below average reviews.